# Underdetermined system with inequality constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have an underdetermined system of equations of the form

\begin{equation}
Ax = b,
\end{equation}
where $A \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m < n$, subject to

\begin{equation}0 \preceq x \preceq c.\end{equation}

1. I would like to know if there is any way to express the feasible set for this problem analytically.
2. Is there any way to obtain any of feasible solutions in closed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is no to both questions.

Of course, you could always try a finite number of test points, including $x=0$, $x=c$, to see if they happen to satisfy $Ax=b$; and you can try the minimum-norm solution $x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$, to see if it happens to satisfy $0\preceq x\preceq c$. If any of these tests hold, then you've found a closed form solution.

But again, in general, you will not be able to. It's a very simple convex optimization problem to solve numerically, though. In fact, it is a linear program, unless you choose a nonlinear function (like the norm of $x$) as an objective function. But there's no reason to do that; I'd just minimize $\sum_i x_i$ in this case, if I didn't have any other preference. Technically, your objective could just be "0" as well, in which case the point it selects will truly be solver dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wonder if there is any condition that can tell us whether the feasible set is empty or not.

Comment: I am sure there is some sort of Farkas lemma that could be constructed here, but it too will not have a closed form solution.

Comment: OK. I got it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did I get this right: 1) Keep the equalities as they are, 2) Convert inequalities to equalities with slack/surplus variables, 3) Pick _any_ objective (cost) function to extremize, 4) Use the Simplex algorithm to find a solution x_i (if any) that satisfies the original equalities and inequalities. Yes?
Also, does the choice of objective function have any impact on the solution?

Comment: @JobStancil depends on the software. Most solvers accept upper and lower bounds on variables so step 3 is not needed. Still others accept both equations and inequalities once again making 3 unnecessary

Comment: @MichaelGrant, thanks. Any pointers to solvers for Java or python? (Not sure if I should search for Simplex or some other term.)